# Strange behaviour of fluentvalidation's SetCollectionValidator

Tags: c#, regex, fluentvalidation

In my project, I am using FluentValidation of .net. Class on which I applied this validation is something like this:

```
[Validation(typeof(InputValidator))]
public class Inputs
{
    public IEnumerable<string> MobileNos { get; set; }
}
```

`InputValidator.cs` file is something like this

```
public class InputValidator: AbstractValidator<Inputs>
{
    public BlockMobileInputsValidator()
    {
         RuleFor(x => x.MobileNos).Cascade(CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure).NotEmpty()
                .Must(x => x.Count() <= 100).WithMessage("List should not contain more than 100 mobile numbers.")
                .SetCollectionValidator(new MobileValidator());
    }
}
```

And `MobileValidator.cs`

```
public class MobileValidator:AbstractValidator<string>
{
    public Mobilevalidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x).Matches("^[6789]\d{9}$").WithMessage("{PropertyValue} is not in correct mobile-number format");
    }
}
```

Now when I pass `{null,"7897897897"}` list to `MobileNos of Input` class, it is not giving any error and list is accepted for further use.
I am not able to understand this strange behaviour. `I also tried this`

```
public class MobileValidator:AbstractValidator<string>
{
    public Mobilevalidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x).NotNull().Matches("^[6789]\d{9}$").WithMessage("{PropertyValue} is not in correct mobile-number format");
    }
}
```

but this also not working for above Input.

Can anyone tell why it is accepting `null` value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why your code does not work but when you change `InputValidator.cs` to the following code, then you can get the desired result:

```
using FluentValidation;
using System.Linq;

public class InputsValidator : AbstractValidator<Inputs>
{
    public InputsValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.MobileNos).Cascade(CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure).NotEmpty()
                                 .Must(x => x.Count() <= 100).WithMessage("List should not contain more than 100 mobile numbers.");
        RuleForEach(x => x.MobileNos).NotNull().SetValidator(new MobileValidator());
    }
}
```

Then the following test passes:

```
using FluentValidation;
using Xunit;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace test
{
    public class InputsValidatorTests
    {
        [Fact]
        public void WhenContainsNull_ThenIsNotValid()
        {
            var inputs = new Inputs();
            inputs.MobileNos = new List<string>() { null, "7897897897" };
            var inputsValidator = new InputsValidator();

            var result = inputsValidator.Validate(inputs);

            Assert.False(result.IsValid);
        }
    }
}
```